# How to search for incompatible Android API usage in my app

Tags: android-sdk-tools

Let's say I have set up my Android application's AndroidManifest.xml as follows:

`<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>`

I am interested in how I can scan my source code for invocations of Android APIs that are not part of the minimimun SDK version I have specified, which in this example is API Level 8.  That way, I can inspect each questionable invocation to ensure that it is properly wrapped with a reflection test, or some other assurance of backwards compatibility, so that it won't crash older devices.  Ideally, I could then mark off this invocation as 'safe' so that it doesn't trigger on subsequent scans.

For example, let's say a developer unknowingly checks in some code that uses `DownloadManager`, an API that is available in API levels 9 and higher.  Because of my 'uses-sdk' statement above, MyApp will build, install, and run on an Android 2.2 (API Level 8) device.  But once the code path invokes the `DownloadManager` method on that 2.2 device, the user will experience an unresolved virtual method exception (crash).  This is what I'm trying to avoid.

Ideally scanning for these potentially-incompatible APIs would be something I can do from the command line, during building; and, it would be able to handle changes to android:minSdkVersion without too much retooling.

Comment: There are many questions much like yours already here (and available through google) that can answer this question.  To start, look at the 'Related' column just below 'Careers 2.0' in the right margin.

Comment: @KevinDTimm: I don't see anyone who asked, or had answered, how to scan for APIs in use that are *not* native to minSdkVersion.  That is what I am asking here.  I _have_ seen a great suggestion to keep bumping the minSdkVersion down (and building) until you get compile errors, to determine the lowest minSdkVersion value you can use.  But it's not the same thing as I am asking here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a hard time myself to find this so I'll answer is clearly (even though this is a 2 year old question).

In Eclipse, right click on the project, click "Android tools" > "Run lint: check for common error".
This will give you a list of all oddities lint can find in your code, including incompatibilities to the minSdkVersion you defined in your manifest (can be found in the list with the category "Correctness").

Comment: Indeed, this produces an error in my Lint Warnings pane, "Call requires API level 16 (current min is 15)".  The Lint details tells me I can place `@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)` at the top of my method if I know what I'm doing (i.e., conditionally verify correct API level at runtime before invoking), thereby suppressing this error.